# Published Cloud with 0 points - Laser scan assembler

Tags: ros, laser-assembler

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bag file gotten from my laser sensor. Currently, I can see the stream of scans with Rviz, but I need to create a 3D view of the robot environment to be used as collision objects for path planning. Then I read about laser_assembler package but it doesn't work for me.

I run the bag file, then launch the `laser_scan_assembler.launch`:

```
<launch>
  <node type="laser_scan_assembler" pkg="laser_assembler" name="laser_scan_assembler">
    <param name="max_scans" type="int" value="400" />
    <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="laser" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

and finally the periodic snapshotter, but I got this:

```
INFO: Published Cloud with 0 points
INFO: Published Cloud with 0 points
```

How could I solve it?

The rosbag info on my file shows:

```
path:        2015-09-25-17-07-26.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    1:59s (119s)
start:       Sep 25 2015 17:07:27.47 (1443218847.47)
end:         Sep 25 2015 17:09:27.14 (1443218967.14)
size:        33.6 MB
messages:    71663
compression: none [44/44 chunks]
types:       rosgraph_msgs/Log     [acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb]
             sensor_msgs/LaserScan [90c7ef2dc6895d81024acba2ac42f369]
topics:      /rosout       7 msgs    : rosgraph_msgs/Log     (3 connections)
             /scan     71656 msgs    : sensor_msgs/LaserScan
```

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219802/published-cloud-with-0-points---laser-scan-assembler/) by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2015-10-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You require two mre things:

1. Remap scan topic to tilt_scan
2. Your transformations (tf messages) are missing.

---

Originally posted by [Shantnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26813/shantnu/) with karma: 86 on 2016-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0